# Getting data from database through Ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, ajax

Is the method used below to get data from a database efficient and optimal? The data is in a MySQL database, and in my server I have a PHP file with the following code to return some information:

```
if($_POST["method"] == "requestBusinessFood") {
    requestBusinessFood();
} 

function requestBusinessFood() {
    $categoryID = $_POST["category"];

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'fooddatabase';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `foodtablebusiness` WHERE category = " . $categoryID;

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $rows[] = $r;
        }

        echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

On the webpage, I have a js file to retrieve the information in the following way:

```
  function createAJAXRequestToPopulateList(category) {
    return $.ajax({ url: '../server.php',
                    data: {method: 'requestBusinessFood',
                           category: category},
                    type: 'post'
    });
  }

function addActivityItem(){
    var selector = document.getElementById("categorySelector");
    ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToPopulateList(selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value);
    ajaxRequest.done(populateList);
}

function populateList(responseData) {
    console.log(responseData);
}
```

Comment: Use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

#### SQL injection vulnerabilities

This code is wide-open to [SQL injection attacks](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection). User input should be sanitized as supplied to the query using parameters (e.g. with [`mysqli_prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [`bind_param()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)).

#### Indentation

The indentation is somewhat consistent but then in some places it increases without a block-level change - e.g. in the PHP code most lines are indented with four spaces, which is very common, and then when `$sql` is declared it increases to eight spaces.

> ```
> $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db); 
>       $sql = "SELECT * FROM `foodtablebusiness` WHERE category = " . $categoryID;
> ```

#### Fetching results

Instead of using a while loop with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` just to push into an array, use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get an array with one call.

#### Selecting fields

Additionally, the SQL query selects all fields - i.e. with `SELECT *`. Instead of selecting `*`, specify the field names needed in order to exclude any fields not needed in the front end.

### Javascript

#### Variable scope

In this line:

> ```
> ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToPopulateList(selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value);
> ```

it makes a global variable `ajaxRequest` because there is no [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) keyword before it. Use `const` to limit the scope to the function `addActivityItem`.

#### Utilizing jQuery

It appears that jQuery is used, given the usage of [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (though if that is wrong then the following won't work). Presuming that is the case, then the other code can be simplified using jQuery utilities.

For example:

> ```
> var selector = document.getElementById("categorySelector");
> ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToPopulateList(selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value);
> ```

can be simplified to the following using the [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
const selector = $('#categorySelector');
const ajaxRequest = createAJAXRequestToPopulateList(selector.val());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the PHP part is neither efficient nor optimal.

Apart from already mentioned issues, your function does too much work, which makes it non-reusable and which bloats your code in general. Remember the rule of thumb: each unit of code should mind its own business. While your function interacts with a client through $_POST and echo, connects to a database, queries a database, formats the results. You have split it into several parts

1. Create a [separate file to connect with a database](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) and just include it in every script that needs a database connection.
2. Create a function that performs a certain SQL query and return the results, so it can be reused for any other kind of request.
3. Write a code that handles a particular request from a client

So the code should be

```
<?php
require 'mysqli.php';

if($_POST["method"] == "requestBusinessFood")
{
    $rows = requestBusinessFood($mysqli, $_POST["category"]);
    echo json_encode($rows);
} 

function requestBusinessFood($mysqli, $categoryID)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM foodtablebusiness WHERE category = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $categoryID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```